# Spinner downdrop with strange text

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I'm developing an Android application with a spinner.

I have this problem:

[image]

This is spinner array adapter code:

```
public class OrderArticlesAdaper extends ArrayAdapter<Article>
{
    private Context mContext;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<Article> articles;

    public OrderArticlesAdaper(Context context, int listItemResourceId,
            ArrayList<Article> dbArticles)
    {
        super(context, listItemResourceId, dbArticles);

        this.mContext = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = listItemResourceId;
        this.articles = dbArticles;
    }

    public ArrayList<Article> getArticles()
    {
        return this.articles;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return articles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Log.v("OrderArticlesAdaper", "getView.postion: " + position);
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        Article article = articles.get(position);
        if (article != null)
        {
            TextView formNameView = (TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            formNameView.setText(new Long(article.getArticleId()).toString());
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

And this is an asynctask to load spinner data:

```
private class LoadEReportAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog loadingDialog;
    private EReport eReport;
    private QAP qap;

    public LoadEReportAsyncTask(Context context)
    {
        Log.v("LoadEReportAsyncTask", "constructor");
        eReport = null;
        qap = null;

        this.mContext = context;
        loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        loadingDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        loadingDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.msg_loading_ereport));
        loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        loadingDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        Log.v("LoadEReportAsyncTask", "doInBackground");
        DBManager dbMan;
        dbMan = new DBManager(mContext);

        // Es un nuevo EReport, por lo tanto lo creo en la base de datos.
        if (eReportId == -1)
        {
            // Time In
            TextView aux = (TextView)((EReportFinalInspecActivity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.timeInVal);

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            String timeIn = df3.format(c.getTime());
            aux.setText(timeIn);

            eReport = new EReport();
            eReport.setOrderId(orderId);
            eReport.setQapId(qapId);
            eReport.setTimeIn(timeIn);

            eReportId = dbMan.insertEReport(eReport);
        }
        else
        {
            eReport = dbMan.getEReport(eReportId);
        }

        qap = dbMan.getQPA(params[0]);
        ordersArticles = dbMan.getOrderArticles(orderId);

        selectedArticles = new ArrayList<Article>(ordersArticles.size());

        return true; // TODO: Controlar los errores
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        Log.v("LoadEReportAsyncTask", "onPostExecute");

        EReportFinalInspecActivity act = (EReportFinalInspecActivity) mContext;
        if (result)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.msg_ereport_got_correct), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            act.fillEReport(eReport, qap);
            Spinner articleSpin = (Spinner) act.findViewById(R.id.articlesSpiner);
            OrderArticlesAdaper spinAdapter = new OrderArticlesAdaper(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ordersArticles);
            spinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            articleSpin.setAdapter(spinAdapter);

            // TODO: Esto hay que cambiarlo porque siempre habrá QAP.
            if (qap != null)
                act.eReportHasQAP(true, qap.getName());
            else
                act.eReportHasQAP(false, null);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.msg_ereport_problem), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        loadingDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What datatype does Article.getArticleId() return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
formNameView.setText(Long.toString(article.getArticleId()));
```

**Edit:**

This is just a guess, but maybe Android is filling the spinner dropdown textviews using Article.toString(), since your adapter handles objects of type Article.

To test this, override toString in your Article class.

```
public class Article {
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        mArticleId.toString(); // This is the private field holding the long id.
    }
}
```

Comment: Right. Container item should override `toString()` method, returning nessesary text.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the clean way of doing it but can you try

```
formNameView.setText(article.getArticleId()+"");
```